# XSLT How does following-sibling in template match work?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a basic question about understanding preceding/following-sibling in templates.

I have the following XML Source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <a>A</a>
    <b>B</b>
    <c>C</c>
    <d>D</d>
    <e>E</e>
    <more>FGHIJ</more>
</root>
```

I want to copy everything except the nodes on the same level after `<c>`. This shoud be done in a generic way. 
So I wrote this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[following-sibling::c]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:text>modified</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Coud someone please explain why `<xsl:template match="*[following-sibling::c]">` in this case matches everything before `<c>` and how to do this the right way? As I expected it to match everything after `<c>` and do not understand why. 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your match statement `*[following-sibling::c]` matches every element which has an `<c>` element that comes after it in document order (where those elements share a parent element).  However, your identity transform will still include the ones that follow `<c>`

Given that, try removing your second template and adding the following:

```
<xsl:template match="*[preceding-sibling::c]"/>
```

That will suppress these elements after `<c>`. It's often easier to suppress the elements you don't want in this sort of case than it is to try to include the other elements.

Comment: Thanks Nic! I already discoverd that preceding-sibling does the job but it was not clear why. Now I got it - I thought about preceding and following the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

`match="*"` matches any element and `match="*[following-sibling::c]"` matches any element for which the condition in the predicate in square brackets holds, namely any element which has a following sibling which is a `c` element.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I thougt about following and preceding the wrong way. Now I got it.